# Gaining better performance with inotify-tools and unison.

Tags: data-synchronization, unison, inotify-tools

I use `inotify-tools` and `unison` to synchronize folders between machines.
Because I have a large folder to synchronize, I just simply write an `inotifywait` script to do the job automatically.
Is it sensible to let `inotifywait` to monitor the subdirectories of the large folder to gain a better performance?

Comment: after doing some research,just monitor the root directory will be ok

Comment: Pay attention to the performance impairment while watching the root directory of a large tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should get better performance if you ditch `inotify-tools` and just use unison's native support for watching your folders for changes. By using `inotify-tools` and then calling `unison` when a change occurs, `unison` has to "*re-find*" the change before it syncs. You could instead add the line `repeat = watch` to your unison profile and `unison` will run continually and sync whenever there is a change. It detects the change with its own file-watcher utility `unison-fsmonitor` that communicates directly with unison.

For more information, check out [the latest changelog for unison 2.48.3](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#news)  with major changes to `unison-fsmonitor`.

Comment: If only `repeat= watch` worked out of the box on Ubuntu. It still doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The `unison-fsmonitor` is not provided by ubuntu package until now:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unison/+bug/1558737
- https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/issues/208

If you want it fast locally

```
UNISON_VERSION=2.51.2
echo "Install Unison." \
    && apt install wget ocaml
    && pushd /tmp \
    && wget https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/archive/v$UNISON_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && tar -xzvf v$UNISON_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && rm v$UNISON_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && pushd unison-$UNISON_VERSION \
    && make \
    && cp -t /usr/local/bin ./src/unison ./src/unison-fsmonitor \
    && popd \
    && rm -rf unison-$UNISON_VERSION \
    && popd
```