# How to get Lsyncd's file-watching capability with Unison's two-way sync?

Tags: synchronization, master-slave, unison, lsyncd

I have used Lsyncd before, but it just works for one-way sync, so only the Master can copy files to the Slave server. I have found another solution for two-way sync between Master and Slave with Unison, but Unison doesn't watch for changes in real-time like Lsyncd does.

Is it possible to combine the functionality of Lsyncd and Unison? What I want is for Lsyncd to watch for changes, then notify Unison to do the syncing.

Answer (score 3):

But Unison CAN watch for file changes in real-time. Just add the line

```
repeat = watch
```

to your Unison profile. Unison will detect changes with its own (external) file-watcher utility unison-fsmonitor that communicates directly with Unison. For some more information, check out the [changelog for unison 2.48.3](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#news) with major changes to unison-fsmonitor.

But if you *really* want something to watch for changes and then tell Unison to run, you should look at inotify-tools, although [I don't recommend doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16496624/2671341).